# AMP-HTML - Combine extended components? - Browser-Caching Issue - PageSpeed Insights

Tags: amp-html

is there a way to combine the AMP extended components to one script? When you use a lot of components, Google PageSpeed Insights gets crazys [Google PageSpeed Insights Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ouOI.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible. You should file an feature request on the AMP Github project.